# Node.js - The function does not return data in select from table

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to retrieve the unique id from the database and store them into the object (`userslist`).

Why can not I retrieve data into an object?
Object `userslist` is empty {}

I have this function in Node.js:

```
getOnlineUsers: function()
    {
        var userslist = {};

        client.query(
            'SELECT DISTINCT Aid FROM online',
            function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                if (results.length > 0) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var reader = results[i];                        
                        userslist[reader['Aid']] = {
                            fbid: reader['Aid']
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }
            );
        return userslist; 
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to use NodeJS, first priority is to learn to deal with asynchronous code.

Comment: The same could be said for any serious javascript.

Comment: How can I change this function?

Comment: @amnotiam could you build a proper answer showing how to asynchronously use the returned data ?

Comment: @JohnMalcom you can't have this function returning the data. You can for example provide your function a callback that will be called with the data as parameter.

Comment: @dystroy: Proper will depend on the context. Perhaps the object that owns `getOnlineUsers` should be an event emitter. Perhaps a callback should be passed. Perhaps the relevant code could be coded directly into the method in this case. All depends.

Comment: ...and if you know Node, you know that it has a large asynchronous API, so I'd say that learning to code asynchronously is especially relevant.

Comment: @amnotiam Can you help me with change the code of the function?

Comment: JohnMalcom: Because the `clients.query` is asynchronous, the `getOnlineUsers` will return long before you get a response for `clients.query`. As @dystroy stated, you can't *return* the result because of this. Any code that relies on the response from `clients.query` needs to be invoked within the callback, which is your `selectCb` function. So you either need to write the relevant code in that callback, or you need to allow `getOnlineUsers` to receive a function argument, which it invokes in the callback, or you need to simply call some other function in the callback, and pass it the new data.

Comment: ...I don't know enough about your code to tell which one is the proper solution. It's the concept that you need to grasp if you're going to use NodeJS to any degree.

Comment: @amnotiam Thank you. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one example of what was discussed in the comments above.

Pass a callback to `getOnlineUsers`...

```
my_obj.getOnlineUsers(function(u_list) {

    /* do something with the user list */

});
```

And have `getOnlineUsers` receive the callback argument, and invoke it...

```
// receive the callback----v
getOnlineUsers: function(cb_func) {

    client.query(
        'SELECT DISTINCT Aid FROM online',
         function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            var userslist = {}

            if (results.length > 0) {

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var reader = results[i];                        
                    userslist[reader['Aid']] = {
                        fbid: reader['Aid']
                    }
                }       
            }
            cb_func(userslist); // <-- invoke the callback, passing the data
        });
}
```

This is one approach, but basically illustrates that the continuation of the flow of code needs to take place in the callback passed to `client.query`.